# Deprecation of createObjectURL and replace with the new HTMLMediaElement.srcObject doesn't work for Webcam stream

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, html5-video, html5-audio

I get the warning that a function will be deprecated in Chrome future release.

It's this script:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({
        video: true
    }, (stream) => {
        this.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        this.stream = stream;
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

That records webcam so I can save it, but the following warning is shown in the console:

> [Deprecation] URL.createObjectURL with media streams is deprecated
>   and will be removed in M68, around July 2018. Please use
>   HTMLMediaElement.srcObject instead.

But when I change:

```
this.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
```

To

```
this.src = window.HTMLMediaElement.srcObject(stream);
```

It doesn't work anymore like it did before..

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Your misunderstanding what `HTMLMediaElement` is.

It is the JavaScript Class/Prototype that represents a HTML `<audio>` or `<video>` tag whether it's in the HTML or not.

For a more class like explanation
`<audio>` on the page is an object of type `HTMLAudioElement` and that extends `HTMLMediaElement` and that in turn extends `HTMLElement`.

If you get the media element with `querySelector()` or `getElementById()` or create a media element in JavaScript with `createElement("audio")` or `createElement("video")`
you'll get an instance of `HTMLMediaElement`.

In your case `this` is an object of `HTMLMediaElement` class.

With JavaScript, as a rule of thumb if the object type name starts with HTML it is referring to an HTML Element / Tag.

All you need to do is change

```
this.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
```

to

```
if ('srcObject' in this) {
  this.srcObject = stream;
} else {
  this.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}
```

This is taken from [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject)

Comment: this doesn't answer the question for me. createObjectURL was not only used for displaying video, it was also used for downloading files. the src tag does not accept a srcObject, now there is no solution for downloading a file.

Comment: @tatsu What are you talking about the answer is correct for the question asked if it does not work for you open a question and give us your code to see what is wrong with it, don't just say does not answer the question for me, well then you have a different question.

Answer (score 9):

Replacing `this.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);` by `this.srcObject = stream;` should fix the problem.

Comment: the `<src` DOM tag does not accept the srcObject value.

Comment: how do you turn the result of a FileReader() into a stream

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome you can use:

```
video.srcObject = stream;
```

instead of:

```
this.srcObject = stream;
```

Comment: only if `video` variable is setup with the scopes required and points to the video element you're wanting to effect at no point in the OP's code is `video` defined