# Chrome update-Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL'

Tags: javascript

I'm taking an image from the webcam and storing it to the server. Everything was working fine until I got the chrome update today. My latest chrome version is:

> Version 71.0.3578.80 (64 bit)

This line is throwing an error:

```
camera.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
```

> Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found
>   that matched the signature provided.

According to this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101408/deprecation-of-createobjecturl-and-replace-with-the-new-htmlmediaelement-srcobje). I applied the code

```
try {
  this.srcObject = stream;
} catch (error) {
  this.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}
```

Its not displaying the camera feed.

For reference - This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dannymarkov/cuumwch5/) code is not working on my chrome anymore.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's just been removed from the current version of Chrome. I suddenly started getting this error after it updated. I have no idea why it never printed deprecation warnings before today.

Instead of setting the `src` property to `URL.createObjectURL(stream)` you're now supposed to set the `srcObject` property to the stream directly. It seems to be working in Chrome and Firefox.

Source: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/10/chrome-71-deps-rems

Answer (score 20):

Since google update version 71, this issue is generating. I also faced this issue. But now I got the solution to it. Here is the solution:

Replace

```
videoElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(screenStream);
```

to

```
videoElement.srcObject = screenStream;
```

Comment: is videElement free to change into another name?
like can I change videoElement into img.srcObject = screenStream? or another name?
to it have rule for naming the const?

Comment: It's a video element that means it's an element in which the video will be playing. Its name can be whatever you want.

Comment: my code is like this `<img src={URL.createObjectURL(screenStream)} />`
so how I can convert into `videoElement.srcObject = screenStream`?

Comment: I am downloading word doc as   saveAs(result, name+'_resume.pdf'); in this case how its is?

Comment: @NithinPaul It's only for live video calling, not for downloads. To download you can do one thing. Record the whole call and then do download the same.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this?

```
try {
  camera.srcObject = stream;
} catch (error) {
  camera.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In chrome, it works fine if you use:

```
video.srcObject = stream;
```

Instead of:

```
this.srcObject = stream;
```

[See printscreen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VShS.png)

Comment: Nice work.
Does this also work for mobile browsers as well?

Comment: Yes, I am using it in my own camera app.

Comment: in video.srcObject, can I change video into another const name?

like img or etc. ?

Comment: Hello @jhon, yes, absolutely, "video" is just the name of the video element:
var video = document.getElementById('video'); but it could be: var my_image = document.getElementById('video');